# Short version of longer quotes

Tags: quotes, resources

Where can i find the full version of the shorter quotes?

Such as:

> Great minds think alike

is actually a shorter version of

> Great minds think like, small minds rarely differ.

Probably this is just a  pop version -

> Curiosity killed the cat but satisfaction brought it back

I have been looking for them since a while now, ever since I heard about Scooby Doo's darker interpretation.

EDIT - Are there any resources or website where i can find more of these?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because as a request for resources it belongs either on ELU.meta or say Literature.SE.

Answer (score 1):

"Great minds think alike" as the first recognizable version of the phrase comes from Carl Theodor von Unlanski's *The woful history of the unfortunate Eudoxia*, 1816

This was plucked from a very useful source that should answer this and your other curiosities. https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/great-minds-think-alike.html